# Error in just Samsung Galaxy S7 edge (maybe other unknown devices too)

Tags: java, android, debugging

My project is shared in [this GitHub link](https://github.com/Kickass86/NewMPAS). Though i did run and test my android app with couple of devices successfully, There is "Stop Working"/"keeps stop running" message in `Galaxy S7 Edge`. My test cases were `Sony xperia Z3` and `LG L70`.

I tried to send error message to a server via `SendError` Service while catching `exception` in try/catch statement but it seems error is out of those statement and user(with S7 edge) reported that the problem has been existed.

So in general form, how can someone find what's wrong with a code while haven't got access to specific device(which error occurs)? obviously i couldn't test my app on every device(nor can i buy S7 Edge just to test my app).

If you saw my code and by chance know which part causing this to happen, please notify me.

Notice: The error occurs in couple of seconds. I guess it happens in `StartActivity` or `MainActivity` or `VersionUpdate`.

**Update:** I don't have the `Log` and i can't use `Firebase Crash Reports` because of Sanctions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Few things:

Firstly, do you have some sort of crash reporter embedded into your app? If not, I would recommend using Firebase Crash Reports. this way, you can easily see crash reports and stack traces, as well as device information, which is useful for when your app crashed due to a device-specific crash.

Second, do you have a complete crash log for the Galaxy S7 Edge? If so, please post it here, it would be nearly impossible to help you without the details of the crash

Comment: Thanks for quick response. If i could get my hand on S7 Edge, i would probably solve it, so no i don't have the log. I live in Iran so as i mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776992/google-restricts-fcm-service-based-on-ip-address-is-there-any-other-free-androi) i can't use some google services such as `Firebase` due to sanctions.

Comment: Try Crashlytics: https://try.crashlytics.com/
I did not see a notice there, regarding embargoed countries

Comment: Thanks alot. I'll check it and get back to you with upvote and accept answer.